# Why class attribute not work in WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I used default ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application Template and Visual Studio Create **InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute** in Filters Directory and create account Controller like this:

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
/* Some Default Actions like Login, LogOff, Register, ...*/
}
```

and i try to make AccountController WebAPI, my code is:

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class APIAccountController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public string Login(string UserName, string Password, bool RememberMe)
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Login(UserName, Password, persistCookie: RememberMe))
        {
            return "OK";
        }

        return "Failed";
    }
}
```

now, when i call api, its break in this line:

if (WebSecurity.Login(UserName, Password, persistCookie: RememberMe))

and said: **You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class.**

i ran it in **InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute** and webapi controller is same with controller.

why attribute not run in WebAPI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[InitializeSimpleMembership]`-attribute inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`

Action filters for Web API need to inherit from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`, so the filter is not actually getting executed on your Web API controller.

There's two things you can do:

- Either implement your own filter, inheriting from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`
- Add the following code to your `global.asax`

  ```
  private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
  private static object _initializerLock = new object();
  private static bool _isInitialized;

  protected void Application_Start()
  {
      // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start 
  LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock); 
  }
  ```

For this to work you need to move the logic from `InitializeMembership` into a separate class and make sure you can access it from the `global.asax`.